# Transaction Scope not rolling back with async/await

Tags: c#, transactions, async-await, ms-access-2010, oledb

I'm having an issue getting my transaction scope to rollback while using async/await. Everything works as it should without the transaction scope, but whenever I intentionally cause an exception (duplicate primary key on the insert for 2nd iteration), no rollback (for the update) or any sort of transaction related error occurs.

- I should also note that **unless** "OLE DB Services=-4" is in the connection string, I receive the error: 
  "The ITransactionLocal interface is not supported by the 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider. Local transactions are unavailable with the current provider."

The code in the button event handler below is just an example for testing the transaction scope. The main goal is to be able to update multiple tables in a loop that's contained in a transaction asynchronously, so I can avoid UI deadlocks and perform rollbacks for any exceptions that may occur during the loop. Any alternatives or suggestions to my problem are  appreciated, thanks :)

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int customerCount = 150;  // First 150 rows of customer table
                TransactionScope transaction = null;

                using (OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection(Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; OLE DB Services=-4; Data Source = " + filePath))
                {
                    dbConn.Open();
                    using (transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < customerCount; i++)
                        {

                            // Update field indicating customer made an invoice
                            var taskName = sql.executeAsync("UPDATE Customer SET lastInvoiceDate = @date WHERE customerID = @custID", dbConn,
                                new OleDbParameter("@date", DateTime.Today),
                                new OleDbParameter("@custID", i));

                            // Insert new invoice - Breaks here
                            var taskInsert = sql.executeAsync("INSERT INTO Invoice VALUES (1, 'thisisatestinvoice', '$100.50')", dbConn);


                            await Task.WhenAll(taskName, taskInsert);
                        }
                    }

                    // All updates executed properly
                    transaction.Complete();
                }
            }
            catch (AggregateException exception)
            {
                foreach (Exception ex in exception.InnerExceptions)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

public async Task executeAsync(string dbQuery, OleDbConnection dbConn, params OleDbParameter[] parameters)
        {
            var dbComm = new OleDbCommand(dbQuery, dbConn);

            if (parameters != null)
                dbComm.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

            await dbComm.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

Comment: So how are you intentionally causing an exception?   Looks fine to me unless I'm missing something:)

Comment: In your example you first rolling transaction back (by disposing it), and then calling Complete. Complete it before closing connection. Also try to run sql commands one by one (instead of running in parallel and awaiting all). Also wrap connection in using - now you are not closing it if exception occurs.

Comment: Sorry guys, I added more context and updated the post to show more what my intentions are. Basically what's happening is the transaction and queries will complete properly the first time, however when I attempt to cause an exception and initiate a rollback (I get a duplicate Primary Key value exception for the insert on 2nd iteration), the update isn't rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the transaction scope to work, and I'm not entirely sure what the issue is, I think it's due to me being on ACE.OLEDB.12.0, but I found another alternative with OleDbTransaction that will rollback if any failures occur.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        { 
            using (OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection(SQLWrapper.CONNECT_STRING))
            {
                dbConn.Open();
                OleDbTransaction dbTrans = dbConn.BeginTransaction();

                var taskName = sql.executeAsync("UPDATE Config SET Busname = @name", dbConn, dbTrans,
                     new OleDbParameter("@name", "name"));

                var taskInsert = sql.executeAsync("INSERT INTO Callout VALUES (16, 'ryanistesting')", dbConn, dbTrans);

                await Task.WhenAll(taskName, taskInsert);
                dbTrans.Commit();
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task executeAsync(string dbQuery, OleDbConnection dbConn, OleDbTransaction dbTrans, params OleDbParameter[] parameters)
    {
        using (var dbComm = new OleDbCommand(dbQuery, dbConn))
        {
            if (parameters != null)
                dbComm.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

            if (dbTrans != null)
                dbComm.Transaction = dbTrans;

            await dbComm.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you know the answer by now as is' been a while. Same issue happened to me. Thing is that when using ConfigureAwait(false) you are telling the runtime to pick any free thread from the thread pool instead of waiting for the previous used when calling the async method. A different thread is used with a  different context, creating another connection under the same transaction scope which was meant for only one connection. Then the transaction gets promoted to a distributed transaction. That was my experience, I had to abandon the idea of using async as it best and wait to for the previos thread to finish by not using configureAwait(false) or Task.WhenAll. Hope that help!